# Error passing project to production in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very basic application with `Vuejs` which I want to upload to production to test it, run the command

```
npm run build
```

Which created a `dist` folder with an`index.html` and the `js, css, img` folders, when uploading these files to my server in the browser console I get the following errors

> app.b77b1ab7.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.c83b8068.js:1 Failed to load resource:
>   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> chunk-vendors.512d43c3.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /css/carousel.b4d817f1.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /js/carousel.91739f99.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with 
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /css/input.72e671f5.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /css/home.0094a1a4.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /js/input.05cf4a61.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /js/home.762faa19.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.c83b8068.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.b77b1ab7.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)

I don't understand very well why he tells me he can't find the files, I don't know if he forgot to configure something else before doing the `npm run build`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Most likely you are missing some package... Check package.json and check if you have needed packages on dev only

Comment: Have you checked that the files on the server are actually named as in the error messages ? There is a discrepancy between `index.html` and the rest of the files.

Comment: Perhaps are you using vue-router's history mode ? Or maybe you misconfigured your webserver ? Those 404 error seem very familiar to me, and it was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need to serve the directory over `HTTP`. It does not work over `file://`

So you need to define `publicPath` in `vue.config.js` file.

The file by default does not exists. You need to create manually `vue.config.js` file in a root location of your project, i.e. On the same level where is `package.json`.

After you create `vue.config.js` file you should define `publicPath` like below.

**`vue.config.js` file:**

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: ''
}
```

At the end you can build (`npm run build`) your project and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing all

```
<link href="/css/.....> 
<link href="/js/.....>
```

of index.html to

```
<link href="css/.....> 
<link href="js/.....>
```

Hope it may works.

Answer (score 0):

in vue.config.js file just add
**module.exports = {
publicPath: "",
};**

the vue.config.js file must exist in the root directory with package.json file